# I want to show the status bar with back color in my Flutter Application

Tags: android, flutter, show, statusbar

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
```

void main() {
runApp(MyApp());

```
  SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([SystemUiOverlay.bottom]);
}
```

I used this to hide the status bar Now I want my status bar again by commenting this I did not get the status bar back, What I can do?

Comment: If you are using `Hot Reload` option, then try `stop` and `restart` the app, if not works, try `flutter clean` and run again.

Answer (score 0):

```
  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
statusBarColor: Colors.transparent,
statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark,
```

));
**by using this I resolved the issue**